# count number of a solution of an integer equation

Tags: combinatorics, arithmetic, square-numbers

How to count all couple of strictly positive integers (u,v) such that the following expression also lends an integer?

$$\frac{v}{u}\cdot \left[2v-\sqrt{\left(2v\right)^2-u^2}\right]$$

with 
\begin{cases}v\leq10^9\\u<2 v\end{cases}

Comment: Are the brackets in the expression just brackets, or are they a floor function?

Comment: there are just brackets ...

Comment: Set the expression $=k$, isolate the square root, then square both sides. simplify and note that $k$ is relatively prime to $k^2 + 1$. Identify the solutions to this equation that provide the correct sign for the original equation. Count them.

Comment: @PaulSinclair   I came up with the result $k = 2.u (1 + \sqrt{1-u^2/4v^2})$ but I don't really know how to go further ....

Comment: You inverted the $\frac vu$ and used $\frac uv$ instead, which is wrong (unless it is your original post that is wrong - I don't know which one you made the error in). But also you ignored everything I said other than setting it equal to $k$. Do you not understand what I mean by "isolate the square root" (i.e., bring everything other than the square root term to the other side of the equation)?

Comment: @PaulSinclair you are right I made a mistake in the first place, however, I am still stuck. If I set my expression equals to k and isolate the square root on one side it gives me $\sqrt{(2v)^2-u^2} = 2v-u.k/v$, then squaring both side gives me an expression of second order in k $k^2-4.k.v^2/u+v^2=0$ but if I solve this one I get back to my original equation  $k = \frac{v}{u}\cdot \left[2v+/-\sqrt{\left(2v\right)^2-u^2}\right]$. Can you please tell me what I am missing ? Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$k = \frac vu\left(2v - \sqrt{(2v)^2 - u^2}\right)$$
Note that $k > 0$. Isolating the square root gives
$$\frac{2v^2 - ku}v = \sqrt{(2v)^2 - u^2}$$
Which tells us two things. First, that $\frac{2v^2-ku}v > 0$, or since $v > 0$, that $$ku < 2v^2$$
Second, by squaring both sides,
$$\frac{4v^4 - 4v^2ku + k^2u^2}{v^2} = 4v^2 - u^2$$
$$\left(\frac {ku}v\right)^2 = 4ku - u^2$$

Since the right side is integer, so is the left, which means that $v \mid ku$. Let $r = \frac {ku}v$, which by the above is an integer with $0 < r < 2v$. Then $$r^2 + u^2 = 4rv$$
Now notice that $4v^2 - u^2 = 4v^2 - 4rv + r^2 = (2v-r)^2$. Which suggests another variable change: let $w = 2v-r$, so $0< w < 2v$. Then
$$(2v)^2 = u^2 + w^2$$
Which is an equation whose solutions are well-studied. So I'll leave it to you to trace down the rest (though note that $2$ must also divide $u$ and $w$).